# Rules for top-level function definitions order in Racket and Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, racket

I found out that top-level declarations order does not seems to matter. Is there any documentation about that topic? I don't quite understand it.

Examples showing that a function can be called without being defined

```
#lang racket

(define (function-defined-early)
  (function-defined-later))

(define (function-defined-later)
  1)

(function-defined-early)
> 1
```

```
;; Common Lisp

(defun function-defined-early ()
  (function-defined-later))

(defun function-defined-later ()
  1)

(print (function-defined-early))
> 1
```

Comment: bodies of functions aren't evaluated until they are called -- you may get compiler warnings if you call unknown functions when you compile a file

Comment: It's different from Clojure, where defining a function, having a call to an undefined function, is an error.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Are you serious? Yet they insist it's a Lisp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Common Lisp it's a bit complicated, since implementations can use interpreted code, compiled code and heavily optimized compiled code.

**Function calling in simple compiled code**

For example SBCL by default compiles all code. Even the code entered via a read-eval-print-loop:

```
* (defun foo (a) (bar (1+ a)))
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (BAR (1+ A))
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::BAR
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     BAR
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
FOO
```

Since the function gets compiled immediately, the compiler sees that there is an undefined function. But it's just a warning and not an error. The generated code will call the function `bar`, even if it is defined later.

**Symbols have a function value**

In Common Lisp the function objects for global functions are registered as symbols.

```
* (fboundp 'foo)
T
* (fboundp 'bar)
NIL
```

`bar` has no function definition. If we later define a function for `bar`, then the code of our earlier defined function `foo` will call this new function.

How does it work? The code in `foo` does a lookup at runtime to get the function value of the symbol `bar` and calls that function.

Thus we can also redefine `bar` and `foo` will call the new function.

**Late Binding**

The concept of doing runtime lookup of functions is often called **late binding**. This was described for Lisp in the 1960s.

Thus a call of a global function

```
(bar 1 a)
```

is conceptionally basically the same as

```
(if (fbound 'bar)
    (funcall (symbol-function 'bar) 1 a)
    (error "undefined function BAR"))
```

Keep in mind that this is a simplistic model and in reality a Common Lisp *file compiler* may use more aggressive optimizations (like inlining), where there is no runtime lookup.

**The evaluation of function forms**

The Common Lisp standard says in [Conses as Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm):

> If the operator is neither a special operator nor a macro name, it is assumed to be a function name (even if there is no definition for such a function).

Answer (score 2):

Quite apart from the specific semantics of Scheme & CL (which, at least for CL, are fairly complicated and are allowed to vary in various ways), I think you are confused about when functions are called.  I'll consider the CL example and assume a completely naive program which is evaluating the definitions you give, in order.  A program like this:

```
(defun naively-evaluate-file (f)
  (let ((*package* *package*))
    (with-open-file (in f)
      (loop for form = (read in nil in)
            until (eql form in)
            collect (eval form)))))
```

So, OK, what does this function do as it plows through your file?

1. It sees the form `(defun function-defined-early () (function-defined-later))` and evaluates it.  Evaluating a `defun` form defines a function, `function-defined-early` and that function, *when called* will call `function-defined-later` which is not yet defined.  But the function is not called, so there is no problem.
2. It sees `(defun function-defined-later () 1)` and evaluates it, which defines (but does not call) `function-defined-later`.
3. It sees `(print (function-defined-early))`, which calls `function-defined-early` and hence `function-defined-later`, both of which are defined, and prints the result.

So you can see that, in fact, no function is called before it is defined.  Functions are *defined* before functions they call are defined, but those functions are not called at definition time.

---

As an aside, this kind of forward-referenced definition is almost inevitable when defining functions if you want to allow recursion in the language.  Consider this terrible definition of the factorial function:

```
(defun fact (n)
  (if (= n 1)
      1
    (* n (fact (1- n)))))
```

Well, when the system evaluates this definition to define `fact` it's going to see a call to `fact` which ... isn't yet defined.  Well, perhaps you could special-case this (and CL compilers are allowed to do this): assume that that call is, in fact, a call to the function you are defining.

So you can special-case functions which only recursively call *themselves*.  But as soon as you have two or more functions which recursively call *each other*, you can't avoid one of them, at the point where it is defined (not called!), referring to some not-yet-defined function.  So the problem of forward-reference at definition time is all but unavoidable.

(Well, in fact you could avoid it: you could do all your recursion with the Y combinator or something, but while that's entertaining in theory (and to provide incomprehensible answers to homework questions), no-one wants to do that in practice.)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for Common Lisp, if you try to load a single toplevel form (e. g. in SLIME: `C-c C-c`) that refers to a function not known to be defined, you typically get a warning.

However, `load`ing a file (e. g. in SLIME: `C-c C-k`) with several toplevel forms first loads all of them, and only then (typically) checks for missing references.  In any case, missing references at compile or load time are not errors.

This is a bit simplified, but the CLHS chapter is very generic to accomodate very different implementations, and offers (in my view) little guidance.  However, the above is a basic expectation—there is no need for *forward declaration* in a single file.

Comment: SBCL warns for each function in a source file during load if it uses undefined functions. c-c c-k in slime compiles the file and then loads a file. The file compiler defers warnings to the end, but not the loader.

Answer (score 1):

Common Lisp is an assembler at heart. It is very dynamic. Consider the following interaction in CLISP:

```lisp
[1]> (defun foo (x) (defun bar (y) y) x)
FOO
[2]> (bar 4)

*** - EVAL: undefined function BAR
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      You may input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION
 'BAR).
RETRY          :R2      Retry
STORE-VALUE    :R3      You may input a new value for (FDEFINITION 'BAR).
ABORT          :R4      ABORT
Break 1 [3]> :r4
[4]> (foo 3)
3
[5]> (bar 4)
4
[6]> (defun foo (x) (bar (+ 1 x)))
FOO
[7]> (foo 3)
4
[8]> (defun bar (x) (+ 2 x))
BAR
[9]> (foo 3)
6
[10]>
```

It just takes the latest definition of a function in effect at the time of the function call and uses *that*. As we've just seen, you are free to redefine your functions and the new versions will get called if referenced from other functions (in general).

Scheme / Racket is a completely different thing altogether. It is static at heart. Any function references are resolved through the use of *environments*. If you redefine your function in a nested environment, "later" (if it's even allowed to do so), the original version will still be called if it was referenced.

Racket source file's top level functions all belong to the same environment. It is actually an error to try loading source file where some function is defined to call another which isn't actually defined in the same scope, further down in the source file somewhere <sub>(if not in some library)</sub>.

Common Lisp is happy to load such file, because a user is always allowed to define the missing functions later by whatever means -- and there are *plenty* -- at their disposal.